# Find average with the help of third variable

Tags: python, input, average

I just started learning Python so I am making a mistake.

```
Number_One, Number_Two, Number_Three = input("Enter Three Numbers").split()

Average_Number = int(Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three) / 3

print(f"The average of all the numbers is {Average_Number}")
```

I want to print average of three number. Why I am getting 41.0 and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

What you are adding there is `'1' + '2' + '3'` which yields `'123'`, and `int('123')/3` is `41.0`.

You need to cast EACH input into integers before adding them:

```
number1, number2, number3 = input('Enter Three Numbers').split()

average_number = (int(number1) + int(number2) + int(number3))/3
```

Comment: Can you please Explain me if i am using
Average_Number = int(Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three) / 3
 Why it's Printing 41.0(If i am taking 1,2,3 as input)?

Comment: @Vipul Tiwari The first sentence in my answer answers that: What you are adding there is `'1' + '2' + '3'` which yields `'123'`, and `int('123')/3` is `41.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in this line

```
Average_Number = int(Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three) / 3
```

First convert number into integer and then perform any operation. 
2 is not equal to  '2'

For example 
3+3=6 
But
'3'+'3'='33'

I hope you got the point

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Can you please Explain me if i am using
Average_Number = int(Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three) / 3
 Why it's Printing 41.0 (If i am taking 1,2,3 as input)?

Comment: In python what ever your input value it always accept as a string. For example there is not difference between '2' and 's'. Both are strings

Comment: But you can you , built-in eval method to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem in the following line:

```
Average_Number = int(Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three) / 3
```

You have three string. When you're adding them, you're actually concatenating them into one string. For example:

```
'1' + '2' + '3' = '123'
```

Then, you convert the string into int and divide by 3. 
In order to solve the problem you need to convert each string to int, before summing them up, and put them all inside parenthesis:

```
Average_Number = (int(Number_One) + int(Number_Two) + int(Number_Three)) / 3
```

Comment: If i am taking
 Average_Number = int(Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three) / 3
and the input is 1,2,3 then it's giving me 41.0 can you please explain me this?

Comment: @VipulTiwari Because what you're doing is to concatenate the three strings into one, and then convert the one string into int. You need to convert each number into int first. Look at the example I gave you in my answer above...I think it explains it pretty well :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to learn about debugging!  You know that this expression is 41.0:

`int(Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three) / 3`

And you know that what you want is 2.0 -- so how did you get 41?

Let's break it down:

```
>>> int(Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three)
123
```

Oh that's weird -- why does adding 1, 2, and 3 give us 123?  Are those values actually 1, 2, and 3?

```
>>> Number_One, Number_Two, Number_Three
('1', '2', '3')
```

Ah -- these aren't the NUMBERS 1, 2, and 3, they're the STRINGS!  (You can tell by the `'quotation marks'`.)  When you add strings, they get concatenated together, like this:

```
>>> 2 + 2
4
>>> '2' + '2'
'22'
>>> 'foo' + 'bar'
'foobar'
```

So the way to fix it is to convert the numbers to `int`s **before** we add them:

```
number_one, number_two, number_three = input("Enter three numbers: ").split()
average_number = (int(number_one) + int(number_two) + int(number_three)) / 3
print(f"The average of all the numbers is {average_number}")
```

A simpler way to write it is to make them a list instead of three variables.  That way you don't have to deal with so many variable names and parentheses, and it also handles any number of numbers instead of exactly three!

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in input("Enter some numbers: ").split()]
average_number = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
print(f"The average of all the numbers is {average_number}")
```

Or you can use `statistics.mean` to do it in one line:

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> print(
...     "The average of all the numbers is",
...     mean(int(n) for n in input("Enter some numbers: ").split())
... )
Enter some numbers: 1 2 3
The average of all the numbers is 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much sam, it helps alot

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not clear but you can try the following example for calculating the average of 3 number in python 3

```
Number_One, Number_Two, Number_Three = map(int, input("Enter Three Numbers").rstrip().split())

Average_Number = (Number_One + Number_Two + Number_Three) / 3

print(Average_Number)
```